# Nesting `combineReducers` doesn't let to have state without nested objects

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have `bookManageReducer.jsx`:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import {
  REQUEST_BOOKS_PAGE,
  RECEIVE_BOOKS_PAGE
} from '../constants/dashboardConstants'

const books = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_BOOKS_PAGE:
      return action.books
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const booksState = (state = {isFetching: false}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST_BOOKS_PAGE:
      return {isFetching: true}
    case RECEIVE_BOOKS_PAGE:
      return {isFetching: true}
    default:
      return state
  }
}
// ...
const booksManageReducer = combineReducers({ books, employees, employeesList, booksPagination, booksState })

export default booksManageReducer
```

What I want is to combine all intermediate reducers in root reducer `dashboardReducer.jsx`:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'
import booksManageReducer from './booksManageReducer'

const companyId = (state = {}, action) => {
  return state
}

const dashboardReducer = combineReducers({booksManageReducer, companyId, routing: routerReducer})

export default dashboardReducer
```

Which produce this state:

```
Object {booksManageReducer: Object, companyId: 1, routing: Object}
```

instead of

```
Object {books: [], ..., companyId: 1, routing: Object}
```

When I try to use object spread operator:

```
const dashboardReducer = combineReducers({
    ...booksManageReducer, companyId, routing: routerReducer
})
```

It just disappears from the state, and `Object.assign` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't combine them into `booksMangeReducer`. Instead, just export them all as named exports and combine all the reducers at once:

```
export { 
  books, 
  employees, 
  employeesList, 
  booksPagination, 
  booksState 
};
```

Then import them all:

```
import { 
  books, 
  employees, 
  employeesList, 
  booksPagination, 
  booksState 
} from './booksManageReducer'
```

Then combine them all individually with `combineReducers`:

```
combineReducers({
  books, 
  employees, 
  employeesList, 
  booksPagination, 
  booksState,
  companyId,
  routing: routerReducer
});
```

`combineReducers` uses the keys of the passed object to construct state. This will give the desired hierarchy.

Another way which is similar to what you're doing could be exporting an object containing all the reducers themselves, then import the object and spreading it:

```
export default {
    //books, employees, etc.
};
```

Then:

```
import reducers from './booksManageReducer';
```

Finally:

```
combineReducers({
  ...reducers,
  companyId,
  routing: routerReducer
});
```