# How do combine nested reducers?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

In my application, I want to get the following state structure:

```
{
  appName: "Combine Reducers App",
  fruits: {
    apples: [
      { id: 0, name: "apple1", saved: true },
      { id: 1, name: "apple2", saved: true }
    ],
    oranges: [
      { id: 0, name: "orange1", saved: true },
      { id: 1, name: "orange2", saved: true }
    ],
    loaded: false,
    saved: true
  }
}
```

I need individual reduxers to be responsible for managing the state of apples and oranges.
Can you tell me how to type and combine nested reducers?

Source code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-redux-ts-nested-reducers?file=store.ts

If you click the test orange reducer button, the orange reducer will not work.
The nesting need the same as I described above and orange reducer must work on action

Comment: create a different action for the same reducer and on that specific action, update that specific part of the state.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44621515/nesting-combinereducers-doesnt-let-to-have-state-without-nested-objects

Comment: @SarunUK
in js, this works, but typescript swears about type mismatch